# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at user context.<annoynomous>

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button type="submit" onclick="callMe()">show</button>
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="age"></div>
<div id="reservedStatus"></div>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

the javascript file is as following:

```
function callMe() {
var Passenger ;{name='Arun',age=28,reservedStatus=true}
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML="Name:"+name;
document.getElementById('age').innerHTML="Age:"+age;
document.getElementById('reservedStatus').innerHTML="Reservation Status:"+reservedStatus;
}
```

The error is cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at usercontext. Even my script file is after ther the div tag.

Comment: First `var Passenger ;{name='Arun',age=28,reservedStatus=true}` in this line there should be *=* not *;*

Comment: Second read property by property name and dot `Passenger.name`

Comment: The code you provided works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your object format was wrong. Key values are set using `:` not `=`.And to access the properties you have to use the object name along with `.` followed by property name.  Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```js
function callMe() {
  var Passenger = {
    name: 'Arun',
    age: 28,
    reservedStatus: true
  };
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "Name:" + Passenger.name;
  document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = "Age:" + Passenger.age;
  document.getElementById('reservedStatus').innerHTML = "Reservation Status:" + Passenger.reservedStatus;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <button type="submit" onclick="callMe()">show</button>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <div id="age"></div>
  <div id="reservedStatus"></div>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code he gave works fine. Was there any error running that?

Comment: No error with the innerHTML part but this line `var Passenger ;{name='Arun',age=28,reservedStatus=true}`